# Defining Guarded and Unguarded Duplicative Routes (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

Is it possible to define duplicative routes, with one route being guarded and the other being unguarded?  Conceptually I'd like to define a guarded parent route with protected child routes, and unguarded parent route, with unprotected child routes.

Please see below route definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/registration'
  },
  { 
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticatedLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children:[
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '',
    component: NonAuthenticatedLayoutComponent,
    children:[
      { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

If the user is unauthenticated, the intended behavior would skip over the first empty path route, and match with the second empty path route "/registration".

Comment: By design, routes can't have the same path. So not only you can't guard and unguard the same route, but you can't even have different components on the same route

Comment: Nope, I dont think that will work. Angular hits the first matching route, so in this case NonAuthenticatedLayoutComponent would never get hit. What you could do, although it would be different routes, is have the NonAuthenticatedLayoutComponent base path be 'general' or something, and have the AuthGuard redirect from '/registration' to /general/registration'

Comment: Understood, so each route needs to be unique and redirects need to be handled in the AuthGuard?